# Add character end of line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, character

I'm looking for a solution for the following challenge:

I run the following command in PowerShell.

```
Import-Module servermanager
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.Installed -eq "True"} | ft DisplayName, Installed > output.txt
```

Now I want to add a character at the end of each row. How can I do that?

I think I have to add the content into an array, but I don't know how to finish the code.

At the end I have to load the content into the EventViewer. If I send it directly, the event description isn't formatted well.

Answer (score 2):

You could add another field to the records like this:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | ? { $_.Installed } |
    select DisplayName, Installed, @{n='Other',e={'c'}} | ft
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of using `ft > output.txt`, you want something like:

```
foreach { echo ( $_.DisplayName + " " + $_.Installed + " extra_stuff" ) } > output.txt
```

It doesn't give you a nicely formatted table though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little outside the scope of what you directly asked, but I'd suggest skipping the 'write to text file' stage and pass directly to the destination.

```
Import-Module servermanager
$installedFeatures = @()    # Creates a blank array for the features
$output = @()    # Creates a blank array for formatted results

$yourChar    # The character/ string you want to add at the end of each row

$installedFeatures = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed -eq "True"}
foreach($feature in $installedFeatures)
{
    $output += "$($feature.displayName) $($feature.installed) $yourChar"
}
```

Once you've iterated through all the Windows features, your `$output` variable will have an array of strings in the format of `displayName installed $yourChar`. You can then write to disk, or send the object somewhere else (this is the beauty of PowerShell objects!).